# Angular, Item Details

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning **angular** (with ionic framework, includes phone gap)and I am trying to create a single app that lists some data and when you click on one it show details for it. I was able to list all the item but I can't manage how to show details for a single one. I know the issue probably has to do with `$routeParams` but I can't find what is wrong.

app.js

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers'])

.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider) {

    .state('app.list', {
      url: '/list',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/list.html"
        }
      }
    })

    .state('app.staff', {
      url: '/staff/:staffid',
      views: {
        'menuContent' :{
          templateUrl: "templates/staff-details.html",
          controller: 'StaffDetailsCtrl'
        },
      }
    })

});
```

controllers.js

```
.controller('FooCtrl', function($scope) {
   $scope.staff = [
       { id: 1, name: 'Jim', color: 'red' },
       { id: 2, name: 'Bob', color: 'blue' },
       { id: 3, name: 'Peter', color: 'yellow' }
       /*... etc... */
   ];
});

// Review Controller
.controller('StaffDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {

  // Get staff
  alert('yeeeees');
  var id = $routeParams.staffid;
  $scope.staff = $scope.staff.get(id);

});
```

staff-details.html

```
{{staff.id}}<br />
{{staff.name}}<br />
{{staff.color}}
```

**UPDATE**

Link to [Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeuWWNQJ4zKuEE2vqSXl).

Comment: Looks like you're missing code for your `StaffDetailsCtrl`?

Comment: Yes you are right. Forgot to add. I updated the question with it included. @DeanWard

Comment: `staff` is an array , it has no properties like `id` or `name`. The elements of that array do

Comment: @charlietfl - staff-details.html is the detail template. Looking at the code - `$scope.staff` at that point is an individual instance of a staff member.

Comment: @ManolisC. Do you get any errors in the debug console?

Comment: Are you using the angular-ui-router? It looks like you are because of your use of `.state`...

Comment: @DeanWard it wasn't when OP posted that `FooCtrl` was `StaffDetailsCtrl`

Comment: I added a link to plunker with the code so that it is easier to see the code. You can find it [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/LeuWWNQJ4zKuEE2vqSXl).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using the angular-ui-router then your should be injecting `$stateParams` rather than `$routeParams`. So you code will look like:

```
angular.module('app', ['ionic', 'app.controllers'])
    .config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $routeProvider) {

        $stateProvider
            .state('app.staff', {
                url: '/staff/:staffid',
                views: {
                    'menuContent' :{
                        templateUrl: "templates/staff-details.html",
                        controller: 'StaffDetailsCtrl'
                    },
                 }
            })
 });

// Review Controller
.controller('StaffDetailsCtrl', function($scope, $stateParams) {
     // Get staff
    alert('yeeeees');
    var id = $stateParams.staffid;
    $scope.staff = $scope.staff.get(id);
});
```

Comment: As I can see ionic framework already all angular libraries. I tried it but still nothing. It does not even show the `alert`. Btw here is the [link](http://plnkr.co/edit/HIcuIuhtrgcMxpkc7sy5).

Comment: Your plunker doesn't function at all because it's missing any of the external libs it needs. Did you try this in your actual code? Are there errors in the debug console?

Comment: So just to demonstrate that it works I created a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/haQeeSOTXtO8Nve3BNA8) which just uses ui-router rather than ionic... See how that goes :)

Comment: It seems that it works although there is one issue. If I change the code at `StaffDetailsCtrl` to `...name: name,...` it shows **3 plunkerPreviewTarget color**. [Link](http://plnkr.co/edit/5XpwnclARl4mAXtaXEMF?p=preview)

Comment: Right, that's clearly setting the name property to be something from plunker itself. You need to go and fetch the details from some external service based upon the id that was passed...

Comment: I tried your code and it does the same as the plunker link for me. So I guess I am on the right way. Can you give me some further details on what I should do in order to pass more than the `id`?
What about anything like `$scope.staff = $scope.staff.get(id);`

Comment: You generally shouldn't need to pass more than the id. You should use the id to go find the thing that is represented by it. For example call a REST API... I've updated the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/IzCUaJKqTWLiIDNwMOCR) to demonstrate the use of a service containing your data. Plus read about AngularJS [services](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/services) and [$http](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http).

Comment: It worked now! Had to include `underscore.js` and now it works! Thanks for your help and for spending time on this one!